# How to read variables from another class

Tags: c++, string, variables, cout, cin

Hi i am relatively new to c++ i have a bit of experience in java and a lot in batch but i am stuck as how to read information from another class.

What i want to do is have my main class with the story and user input, but store most variables in another class and then access them using code at the required times, for example: i have a part of code where the user inputs their name. i want that input to be stored as a variable in Variables class then when the game says their name (playerName) main class reads playerName in Variables class then displays it in main class. So what is the code i need to put in main class to show the variable from Variable class

Comment: You would be better served by a class or tutorial in C++ rather than asking such basic questions one at a time.

Comment: Mark Ransom is right, this is not an appropriate question for SO, especially without posting any code. All we can do is guess what might have gone wrong. Maybe you didn't put `public` in your variable class but we have no idea because there is not code posted

Comment: Agreed with others... You need to learn more about object oriented design. One of the main points of it is 'data encapsulation', whereby a class contains all the necessary functions and variables to use it inside itself. Variables of the class should NOT be separated from the class.

Comment: You can still use static members of classes and access them anytime

Answer (score 2):

```
// Demonstrates Variable class

#include <iostream.h>      // for cout

class Variables // begin declaration of the class
{
   private:  // begin.  private section
   std::string name; // member variable

   public:   // begin.    public section
     Variables();     // constructor
     std::string getName(); // accessor function
     void setName(int age);  // accessor function
 };

// constructor of Variables,
Variables::Variables()
{
     name = "";
}

// getName, Public accessor function:  
// returns value of name member
std::string Variables::getName() 
 return name;
}

// Definition of setName, public
// accessor function
void Variables::setName(std::string nme)
{
  // set member variable its age to
  // value passed in by parameter age
  name = nme;
}

int main()
{
  Variables variables(); //class object
  std::string name; //local variable

  std::cin >> name; 
  variables.setName(name); //set name

  std::cout << variables.getName();

  return 0;
}
```

Just do the same for all other variables that you need. For more information check out this link 
www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=313"

Comment: For completeness's sake: this works for two classes, too (of course). *Edit:* Example extracted to another answer because formatting in comments was too limited.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Twahanz' answer: the same works if you have a class `Manager` that does things while `Variables` holds the data.

```
class Manager {
  Variables m_my_data;
  ... void some_action();
}

void Manager::some_action() {
  std::cout << m_my_data.getName() << std::endl;
}
```

Just for completeness.